# Run a program with GNU screen and immediately detach after

Tags: scripts, gnu-screen

I am trying to figure out how to write a script which would start program(s) in GNU Screen sessions(s) at system boot.
I am trying this:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -S test -d -m -X $HOME/folder/folder/.program \
screen -S test2 -d -m -X $HOME/folder/folder/.program2 \
```

but the command cant be executed because session is already detached? 
The only thing that i need is run command in screen session and detach this session immediately.

Thanks for answers, but now i faced another problem. Script stops working after i put some variables for my "program and program2". Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -S test -d -m $HOME/folder/folder/.program -f config.cfg
```

for some reason "-f config.cfg" got ignored. I am also tried to quote command and doesnt help too.

Comment: Why the `-X` option?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534386

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Did you really mean to put the `\` at the end of the line? If not then try removing those - they escape the following character.

also, dropping the `-X` helps the setup work for me, for instance:

```
screen -S test -d -m -X touch /tmp/test
```

fails with `No screen session found`, however:

```
screen -S test -d -m touch /tmp/test
```

works fine. As such I suspect the following will work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -S test -d -m $HOME/folder/folder/.program
screen -S test2 -d -m $HOME/folder/folder/.program2
```

---

Remember, that if you run this at boot time, $HOME is not the same as after you log in as a specific user. If you need to run it as a certain user you'll need to use the likes of `su` to run it as that user, and specifying the full path will remove any ambiguity:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -S test -d -m su - username /home/username/folder/folder/.program
screen -S test2 -d -m su - username /home/username/folder/folder/.program2
```

Or, you would call the entire script above as `su - username /path/to/your/script`.

Comment: Thanks for answers, but now i faced another problem. Script stops working after i put some variables for my "program and program2"

Comment: This: `screen -S test -d -m $HOME/folder/folder/.program` almost does exactly what [I'm looking for](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983063/start-a-screen-session-and-run-a-script-without-attaching-to-it) except if folder/.program is finished, the screen session is automatically closed. Is there any way to keep the screen session (shell) running even after the program is done? Perhaps instead of running the program exclusively, start a shell that starts the program and then returns to the shell prompt, or something?

Answer (score 4):

Like Cry Havok mentioned, you can place the program right on the command-line.

If you really must use the -X option, then a) you need to specify the 'screen' command and b) the session needs to exist beforehand.

```
screen -dmS test
screen -S test -X screen $HOME/folder/folder/.program
screen -dmS test2
screen -S test2 -X screen $HOME/folder/folder/.program2
```

Comment: If you put the program on the command-line, screen exits when the program exits; I don't see a command-line flag to keep the screen open if you want to see the console output.

If you start the screen and send the commands separately, as shown here, you may need explicit `sleep` commands to give screen time to start the session before sending the command.

Comment: This answer is very similar to [stackoverflow.com answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6655931/52074) which answers a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534386). I prefer this answer more than @CryHavok because this answer executes your program inside your user's default shell (@CryHavok runs your program without a parent shell so when the program dies or you ctrl-c it the screen session is terminated immediately)