# Starting a program in a Screen session via SSH

Tags: ssh, screen, session

Okay, there are a few similar topics to this one, but what I want to do is run a program in a screen session on a remote computer.

Taking my lead from [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62562/run-a-program-with-gnu-screen-and-immediately-detach-after)

In the hope that it is correct, I am entering the command:

```
ssh  remote@192.168.1.5 "screen -S test -d -m roslaunch startup startup_node"
```

which neither starts a new screen session "test" or runs my script "roslaunch startup startup_node"

I can create a remote session "test":

```
ssh  remote@192.168.1.5 "screen -S test -d -m"
```

But how can I then run a command in it? How is the `screen -X` command used with a named screen?

I have tried, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406823/how-to-execute-a-command-inside-a-screen-session) :

```
 ssh remote@192.168.1.5 "screen -X stuff "roslaunch startup startup_node^M" "
```

but again it doesn't seem to start the process remotely. Both commands work if you are already ssh'd into the remote.

I've also tried to write a script startnav.sh on my remote machine that contains  `screen -S nav -d -m roslaunch startup startup_node`
and I run it by:

```
ssh remote@192.168.1.5 -t "./startnav.sh"
```

This creates the screen instance however it is dead as in the following output

```
    ~$ ssh swarmbot2@192.168.1.5 -t screen -r nav
     There is a screen on:
            4506.nav    (04/06/15 12:30:09) (Dead ???)
     Remove dead screens with 'screen -wipe'.
     There is no screen to be resumed matching nav.
     Connection to 192.168.1.5 closed.
```

Finally, I've followed the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628204/how-to-run-a-command-in-background-using-ssh-and-detach-the-session)

and can get normal bash commands to execute, just not 'roslaunch startup startup_node'

for instance

```
ssh -f remote@192.168.1.5  "screen -dm -S nav htop "
```

will launch a htop session in a separate screen on a remote machine. The `-f` flag seems to be important. But still doesn't work for a roslaunch or a script that contains roslaunch even though it does work if run without ssh. Additionally, for a temporal program such as `sleep 10`, the screen will only exist until that script is completed executing.

Answer (score 1):

As in the final example in the question the problem was not with the ssh or screen environment other than several ROS-specific environment variables were not set up. This was due to `~/.bashrc` not being called on the remote, which set them up for me.

Once I included the setup of specific environment variables namely

```
source /ros/devel/setup.sh
```

the system worked correctly.

Script File `startnav.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

source ~/ros_ws/devel/setup.sh
roslaunch startup startup_node.launch
```

And the call to load the script file:

```
ssh remote@192.168.1.5 -f "screen -S nav -dm ./startnav.sh"
```