# Running bash script in detached screen

Tags: bash, scripts, screen, vpn, openvpn

I could use a little help on this one.  I am a novice scripter at best.  I am trying to write a bash script to connect to my multiple openvpn sites.  I am trying to write the script to open in a detached screen.  I have managed to write the script to connect to the different .ovpn via different variables.  Getting them to run in the detached screen is what I am having trouble with.  Hoping one of you guys might be able to help me.  Currently I am just running

```
screen -S vpn
```

then once the screen opens up, I execute my script to connect to the openvpn sites.  [Here](http://pastebin.com/SfSJJjEC) is my current vpn connection script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "seed-rl" ] ;
then
cd "/home/robbiel811/vpn configs"
echo password | sudo -S openvpn --config seed-rl.ovpn
fi

if [ "$1" = "atl10" ] ;
then
cd "/home/robbiel811/vpn configs"
echo password | sudo -S openvpn --config Atlanta-10.ovpn
fi

if [ "$1" = "atl11" ] ;
then
cd "/home/robbiel811/vpn configs"
echo password | sudo -S openvpn --config Atlanta-11.ovpn
fi

if [ "$1" = "atl12" ] ;
then
cd "/home/robbiel811/vpn configs"
echo password | sudo -S openvpn --config Atlanta-12.ovpn
fi

if [ "$1" = "nyc02" ] ;
then
cd "/home/robbiel811/vpn configs"
echo password | sudo -S openvpn --config NewYork-02.ovpn
fi

if [ "$1" = "nyc10" ] ;
then
cd "/home/robbiel811/vpn configs"
echo password | sudo -S openvpn --config NewYork-10.ovpn
fi

if [ "$1" = "nyc11" ] ;
then
cd "/home/robbiel811/vpn configs"
echo password | sudo -S openvpn --config NewYork-11.ovpn
fi
```

What can I do to make this script run in a detached screen?

Comment: does this helps? http://askubuntu.com/q/62562/294611

Comment: Not really.  I'm still having to run a screen command before I run the script.  What I'm trying to do is run screen from within the script.  So that all I need to do is run the script, and the selected .ovpn is loaded into a detached screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the script is being run inside `screen`, and if not, re-execute it in `screen`:

```
#! /bin/bash

[[ -z $STY ]] && screen -S vpn -d -m "$0" "$@"

if [ "$1" = "seed-rl" ] ;
then
    cd "/home/robbiel811/vpn configs"
    echo password | sudo -S openvpn --config seed-rl.ovpn
fi

...
```

[`STY` is a variable set by `screen`](https://serverfault.com/a/257977/229499), which we can use to detect if we're running in it. `$0` is the current command being executed, and `$@` all the arguments.

Also, consider simplifying your script using associative arrays:

```
#! /bin/bash

[[ -z $STY ]] && screen -S vpn -d -m "$0" "$@"


declare -A configs
config['seed-rl']='seed-rl.ovpn'
config['atl10']='Atlanta-10.ovpn'
# ... etc.
config['nyc11']='NewYork-11.ovpn'

cd "/home/robbiel811/vpn configs"
echo password | sudo -S openvpn --config "${config[$1]}.ovpn"
```

And using `NOPASSWD` `sudoers` rules instead of storing your password in clear text.

Comment: thank you for your advice.  Your script didn't work EXACTLY right like I wanted to.  I modified it a little to what I have below and it's working like I want it!!!  Also, thanks for rearranging my script!  Much neater now!

I can't figure out how to enter a stupid code block here, but anyways, here's a link to the pastebin of the current script that I am using.




http://pastebin.com/ufLAaYVn




Again, Thanks for you help!  Couldn't have done it without you!