# How do I interact with a script started by rc.local?

Tags: command-line, scripts, startup, minecraft

I have a script that runs from `rc.local` (a minecraft server in this case) with which I need to be able to interact (connect to its STDIN and STDOUT later). How can I do this?

Comment: Define "interact" - what do you need to do exactly? What/how would you do it if you started it manually?

Comment: When started manually, it launches an interactive prompt where you can issue commands, OP users, change settings, restart the server, and other such things.

Comment: Could you achieve your requirements by spawning the minecraft process in gnu `screen` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want to do is use `screen`. It allows spawning a process inside its session and detaching from it. Essentially , your question is similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/62562/295286).

The 3 steps that you want to do:

- The line below has to go into your `/etc/rc.local`. Add `&` sign at the end of it ( important !)

  ```
  screen -S MyMinecraftServer -d -m  java -jar ./SOMEFILES/CLEANUP/minecraft_server.1.8.8.jar nogui
  ```
- This is what you'd do from command-line to find your session:

  ```
  screen -ls
  ```

  Example output:

  ```
  There is a screen on:
      1720.MyMinecraftServer  (2017年01月12日 13时54分36秒) (Detached)
  1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-xieerqi.
  ```
- And this is how you attach to it:

  ```
  screen -x 1720.MyMinecraftServer
  ```

**NOTE**: starting minecraft server from `/etc/rc.local` can be a potential security hole. Consider using `su username -c '<screen command here>' &` to run the server as a different user. See also :  https://serverfault.com/a/422952/363611

Comment: An alternative to `screen` would be the somewhat more modern `tmux`. The principle remains the same though the command-line options are all a little different.

Comment: P.S.: Since you're doing all of this from `rc.local`: you shouldn't run a Minecraft server with super-user privileges – especially if it's ports are publicly accessible.