# On startup; Run script as root and create a screen for it

Tags: cron

How can I make a script run on startup as root and also creating a screen for the script?

I think I could just add

```
screen -S name
```

to the top of the script to achieve the screen stuff, but I'm not sure.

Is this all possible to do in crontab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use (in a perl script that is started in /etc/rc.local with

```
su {username} -c '/usr/local/bin/schermen start'
```

The script has a "start","stop" and "restart" options.

):

```
screen -d -m -S {screen_name} {$program_to_start}
```

The man page has a notice om using `-d -m`:

```
-m   causes  screen  to  ignore the $STY environment variable. 
With "screen -m" creation of a new session is enforced, 
regardless whether screen is called from within another screen session 
or not. This flag has a special meaning in connection with the `-d' option:

-d -m   Start screen in "detached" mode. 
This creates a new session but doesn't attach to it. 
This is useful for system startup scripts.
```

Extra:

```
-S sessionname When creating a new session, this option can be used 
to specify a meaningful name for the session. 
This name identifies  the  session  for  "screen -list" 
and "screen -r" actions. It substitutes the default [tty.host] suffix.
```

Comment: Also see: [How do I interact with a script started by rc.local?](https://askubuntu.com/q/871205/158442)

Comment: So what you're saying is create a script that in your example is named schermen and in that script have the screen stuff etc?

Comment: As an example. "schermen" is Dutch for "screens" ;-) Our script is a bit big since we need to open about 10 screens for a 50 instances (and we decided to have each have their own id) (we can start/stop/restart 1, all on 1 instance or all instances remotely).

Comment: Aah, I see! I tried adding the stuff to my `/etc/rc.local` file but when I reboot it doesn't work.. :/ My rc.local -> https://pastebin.com/bzCdJYEQ (ecoround is the user)

Comment: Tried manually executing rc.local and it tells me in terminal: `./rc.local: line 1: !/bin/sh: No such file or directory`, this is probably why it won't work. Any idea why it's telling me this?