# Start a screen session and run a script without attaching to it?

Tags: bash, scripts, session, gnu-screen, background-process

I'm trying to write a script to:

1. Start a new `screen` session
2. Run some program or script within that new screen session
3. Detach from the screen session, while the program from step 2 may still be running in there. If the program from step 2 finishes, immediately or later, the screen session should remain running (detached).

I have been trying all sorts of combinations with `screen -X program` or `screen -S somename` followed by `program` followed by `screen -D`, combining with `-d` or `-m` options which I find in related questions and answers but nothing works.

The closest I could get was this:

```
screen -S MySessionName -d -m myprogram
```

This launches a new screen session in the backgroun, running `myprogram`. 
Except as soon as `myprogram` finishes (sometimes instantly) the screen session terminates, whereas I want to keep it running.

Comment: Have you checked these answers ? >> https://askubuntu.com/questions/62562/run-a-program-with-gnu-screen-and-immediately-detach-after

Comment: @Rooney Yes, and this comes pretty close: `screen -S test -d -m myprogram` except the screen session terminates after `myprogram` is finished. I'll add this in my post for completeness.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Method 1**

I created a demo setup you described here in my machine. I also faced the issue you reported. But adding a small line of `script` solved my issue.

I added the following line at the end of `myprogram`

```
exec $SHELL
```

After your script is finished, the Bash process will replace itself with a new invocation of itself.

**Method 2**

Or you can try the following method in which we start a `detached screen` first and send command to that screen using `stuff`

For this first you need to start a detached screen.

```
screen -dmS MySessionName
```

And then send the script to that screen.

```
screen -S MySessionName -p 0 -X stuff 'myprogram\n'
```

This also worked for me.

Comment: Brilliant, that 2nd method is perfect!

Comment: Hi, Rooney, I'm not sure but probably you could change `sleep infinity` from Method 1 to `exec bash` or `exec $SHELL` - analogically to the solutions provided here: [With a launcher for a terminal application, how can I keep the terminal open after the program is complete?](https://askubuntu.com/q/3359/566421)

Comment: Hi, @pa4080 You are right. thanks for the reply.  Now the screen stays detached and i can continue to the screen, while using `sleep infinity` the only available option is terminate the screen manually.

Comment: The second method is perfect for when my script crashes and doesn't get around to invokating itself. Many thanks!

Comment: When I use method 2 the screen hasn't actually executed the `myprogram` -- it has just typed this into the screens terminal. Is there a way to also execute it?