# Bash file automation

Tags: gnome, bash, scripts, lubuntu, cron

I have scenario like below :

I have a bash file named `infra.sh`. Inside this infra.sh file I have the below commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c "bash ./redis-server.sh && sleep 30"'    
gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c "bash ./redis-client.sh && sleep 30"'    
gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c "bash ./playServer.sh && sleep 30"'    
gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c "bash ./proclient-service.sh && sleep 30"'    
gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c "bash ./infoServer.sh"'
```

Now if I execute the `infra.sh` from a terminal by typing

```
sudo sh ./infra.sh
```

then, all the commands above gets executed in separate terminals. They are running.

But I want to make it in such a way that I will start the `infra.sh` in a manner that all the services will be running in background and as well as the terminal from which I executed the commands for starting `infra.sh` will also go in background.

Is it possible?

thanks in advance.

Comment: So the goal is to start services in background. But why use `gnome-terminal` ?  If  your goal is to preserve output, then consider using `screen` instead. It's often used to start sessions on remote servers, where you can attach to session and detach whenever necessary and don't have to have terminal constantly open. See https://askubuntu.com/q/62562/295286 for details

Comment: hey @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy Yes you are right. Currently I am just watching the req and response printed on the server console. so I am running them in terminal. But I want them not to show in terminal now and instead run those services absolutely in background. what should I do? I do not want all of my service terminal constantly open

Comment: There's several options depending on your needs. If you don't care about the output at all,  you can use `setsid` command. I'd make all commands be like `setsid ./redis-server.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null` and separate each on separate line with `sleep 30`. See [related post] (https://askubuntu.com/a/106359/295286). If you do still care about preserving output, `screen` which i mentioned already would be more appropriate.  You could also consider making the script into a systemd service, but if there's no need to run it at boot, I wouldn't bother. I'd recommend `setsid` first

Answer (score 2):

Two options here:

1. `gnome-terminal <command> &`: will run that command in the background but will be ended if the terminal is closed.
2. `nohup gnome-terminal <command> &`: will run in background and keep running even if the terminal window is closed.

Now run that script with either `&` or `nohup` like so `nohup sudo sh ./infra.sh &` or `sudo sh ./infra.sh &`