# How to automate screen multiplexer to automatically start on a path and execute a file

Tags: scripts, programming, minecraft, sh

I want to automatically:

```
screen -S Test
cd /home/dapkkins/Servers/Bungee
sh start.sh
^Ad
```

My sh file to run my server through ssh

Comment: looks like this is a dupe question ... https://askubuntu.com/a/62574/18025  ... if not pls explain

Answer (score 0):

#### Create [an alias](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-permanent-bash-alias-linux-unix/)

Open up a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + T</kbd>) to edit your `~/.bashrc` and add following

```
alias startbungee='cd /home/dapkkins/Servers/Bungee && sh ./start.sh '
```

then execute commands from .bashrc on current shell (more with `help source`):

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

then launch it using

```
startbungee
```

Comment: Yeah but i want it in a screen terminal